# Python idiomatic process signal interception and forwarding

Tags: python, linux, signals

According to the [Python3 signal documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal) you can set signal handlers for signals with:

```
import signal
previous_handler = signal.signal(sig, new_handler)
```

What is a idiomatic way to intercept all signals with a new handler and subsequently call the previous handler for each signal?